# Vue.js - Detect Nested Property Value Changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm dynamically binding to an Array of objects in a Vue.js 2.0 app. I want to respond to changes as values in that Array change. At this time, as shown in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odcxypx6/3/), I have the following:

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="(col, index) in cols">
          <input :placeholder="col.title" v-model="inputValues[col.prop]" />
        </th>        
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.birthday }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <hr />
  <textarea>{{ inputValues }}</textarea>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cols: [
      { title: 'Name', prop:'name' },
      { title: 'Age', prop:'age' },
      { title: 'Birthday', prop:'birthday' },      
    ],

    inputValues: [],

    items: [
      { id:1, name:'Andreas Winchell', age:47, birthday:'08-04-1970' },
      { id:2, name:'Victoria Hodges', age:80, birthday:'01-24-1937' },      
      { id:2, name:'James Morris', age:59, birthday:'06-14-1958' },      
      { id:2, name:'Larry Walker', age:68, birthday:'08-07-1949' },      
      { id:2, name:'Lee Maynard', age:46, birthday:'04-17-1971' } 
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    buttonClick: function() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.inputValues));
    }
  }
})
```

I can't seem to find a way to bind to changes in any of the values entered into the header. How do I detect and react to property values changes in an Array?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you enter text in the header? I expect, you really don't want an array for `inputValues` but an object. https://jsfiddle.net/odcxypx6/4/

Comment: @Bert - Basically, I want to run a method so that I can apply some logic to the value as it changes. Kind of like a filter.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 3):

### Update 2022

Vue 3 will detect all changes in a reactive array. Square bracket syntax is no longer a limitation.

---

You can use arrays in your data, but **[Vue will not detect direct changes to the array referencing an item by its index](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)**. Vue will detect changes made with push(), pop(), slice() etc.

Arrays like 'Cols' are a disaster. 'Name', 'Age' and 'Birthday' are code (property names), not data. You really don't want to be iterating over an array generating forms like this. Keep it simple and code your three inputs.

Comment: How exactly do you expect v-model to work with the `col.prop` values in an array here?

Comment: I don't expect v-model to work against an array like that. You cannot use square brackets in v-model, and expect the changes to be reactive. But if the data is an array (ie. x anonymous items), we can't just tell him to turn it into an object. Some combination of v-on with push() and slice() will do it, once we know what he's trying to achieve :-)

Comment: You *can* use indexers in v-model, and the modified fiddle linked in my comment shows it. I expect that once the values are completed, OP will want to push the `inputValues` *object* into `items` (adding an `id` along the way) and then clear the `inputValues` object, but OP seems to just be having an issue getting his binding to work for now.

Answer (score 1):

`inputValues` should be an object, not an array.

```
data: {
  cols: [
    { title: 'Name', prop:'name' },
    { title: 'Age', prop:'age' },
    { title: 'Birthday', prop:'birthday' },      
  ],
  // inputValues should be an object.    
  inputValues: {name: null, age: null, birthday: null },

  items: [
    { id:1, name:'Andreas Winchell', age:47, birthday:'08-04-1970' },
    { id:2, name:'Victoria Hodges', age:80, birthday:'01-24-1937' },      
    { id:2, name:'James Morris', age:59, birthday:'06-14-1958' },      
    { id:2, name:'Larry Walker', age:68, birthday:'08-07-1949' },      
    { id:2, name:'Lee Maynard', age:46, birthday:'04-17-1971' } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Even if ts an object, how do I react to changes of the property values in the object. For example, let's pretend that the `name` property changes, how do I run a method when that's updated?

Comment: @ZachTempleton It depends. One way would be to watch that value. What do you want to do when it changes?

Comment: @ZachTempleton I just saw your comment on the question itself. Do you want to filter the table results based on information in the inputs?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here in the VueJS documentation.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.

```
vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
```

To overcome this, both of the following will accomplish the same as `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, but will also trigger state updates in the reactivity system:

```
// Vue.set
Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)

// Array.prototype.splice
vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```